# Number of approvers setting for Merge Request in Group Level

Tags: gitlab, devops, merge-request

In my organization, I would like to set mandatory merge request for all the projects merging into master branch. so, Number of Approvers required should be greater than 0 is what I would like to set for all projects. However, It is tedious and a hectic task to go and set it for thousands of projects, so I am looking for any solution to do it in a single task. My idea is to set the MR approvers > 0 at Group Level thereby all the sub directories and projects in the group level will incur those settings.
I need suggestions and If there is any way like that to do

FYI,
We’re using gitlab.com (SaaS) managed by gitlab itself
I tried do it by Merge Request approvals through API, but this option is also at project level only not at group level

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I contacted gitlab support and the response is we can do "Number of approvers= " in UI for a group level only If we are premium subscribers or else there is no way other than automating the process of enabling it for each and every project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).